# How can I configure return type of third party method with phpstan?

Tags: phpstan

I'm working on a Laravel application. In Laravel you can get the currently authenticated user with `Auth::user()`. The return type of `Auth::user()` is `Authenticatable` (which is an interface provided by Laravel), but I know this function will always return an implementation of a more specific interface.

How can I configure phpstan so that it knows the return type of `Auth::user()` is this more specific interface?

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways you can do this.

- You can use the Laravel extension for PHPStan called [Larastan](https://github.com/nunomaduro/larastan). This extension should help to understand the correct return type of `Auth::user()`
- You can write a `DynamicMethodReturnTypeExtension` More details about it are [here](https://phpstan.org/developing-extensions/dynamic-return-type-extensions).
- You can write a stub file that will overwrite the return type of `user` method. You can read more about stub files [here](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/stub-files).